# Can't post video to /feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a Post on the timeline of a video via the `/feed` endpoint. Following http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ as a reference, I am making this request:

[image]

> **type**: video
>
> **source**: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vocativ-transcoded-video-filesdev/75/web.mp4
>
> **picture**: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vocativ-transcoded-video-filesdev/75/thumbs/00005.png
>
> **message**: My Cool Video

However the video just appears like this one Facebook:

[image]

By docs state:

> source: A URL to a Flash movie or video file to be embedded within the post [string containing the URL]

Any pointers, much appreciated!

Comment: In which language are you developing your app?

Comment: @Shadowfax PHP, but this is using the API Explorer here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=feed

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ refers to the **Post**  object. It's not meant to post video on the wall; but if you want to read any profile's feed objects.

Here's how you can upload a video to the wall:

```
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
   . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
   . "&". $access_token;

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' " method="POST">';
echo 'Browse a video file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';
```

To read more about video- [**Video**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/)

Comment: Hi @Shadowfax, I don't want to upload videos to a user's wall. This is to "share" the video in an article to a wall. The videos are part of news stories, but when the user "shares" the video "object" in the article, it should be playable in Facebook.

Comment: Didn't really got you what you are trying to say; but what you were trying to say in the question is the same what above code do! try it. https://graph-video.facebook.com is what's used while video upload

Comment: I see a different between putting a link to a video on a users wall (and allowing that video to be played inline) and uploading  a 1GB video file to the user's account and having it show up in their uploaded video etc. Your code is uploading the video to that user's account, as it it were "their" video.

Comment: I did, it just linked out to the file video when I did that :/

Comment: So this is what you want no? If you want that it should be played from facebook, then it should be uploaded to the facebook server.!

Comment: Did you see any video apart from youtube that are shared on facebook and not uploaded on facebook?